# Dask dataframe -containing columns that are numpy arrays- conversion to parquet error

Tags: python, csv, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I have a dask dataframe which I am trying to convert to parquet files. This dataframe has columns which are numpy arrays, but column type is "object".

When I try to do this:

```
name_function = lambda x: f"data-{x}.parquet"
data_frame[['numpy_array_col1','numpy_array_col2']].to_parquet('train/',name_function=name_function)
```

I get this error:

```
ArrowTypeError: ("Expected bytes, got a 'numpy.ndarray' object", 'Conversion failed for column INPUT with type object')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

# Other errors

Can only convert 1-dimensional array values
```

I tried using csv's and it worked, but I know its better to use parquet files, and I don't know if reading the csv's will raise logical or syntax error because of the ambiguity of the column types.

```
data_frame[['numpy_array_col1','numpy_array_col2']].to_csv('train/train-*.csv')
```

Update: When reading the csv files, the numpy arrays become of type string, so I have to convert them back to numpy arrays.

I also tried

```
df.to_parquet('somefile', engine='pyarrow')
```

Same thing happens

Comment: `Can only convert 1-dimensional array values` Are the numpy arrays 1 dimension or more?

Comment: They aren't one dimentional

Comment: all comments will center round this: `Can only convert 1-dimensional array values`. Ifthe `objects` are arrays or array like, then this error will surface becuase the dimension > 1.

Comment: So arrays of dimension = 1 will work ? I can try to flatten the arrays then reshape them back after reading the files. Will update later when I try it.

Comment: *Why* do you want to put arrays in a table? Should you be using something like zarr?

Comment: These arrays are then gonna be processed further to create an input vector to an AI model, but I need them to be separate because how they are gonna be processed will differ from one test to the next (an ablation study).

Comment: As for zarr I am gonna look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this workaround. First you flatten all numpy arrays in dask's dataframe. Then you write to the parquet files specifying a schema with pyArrow's list datatypes. Finally you can read the file, but you have to reshape all the previous arrays to thier original shape.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pyarrow as pa

a = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]]).flatten()
b = np.array([[9, 10], [11, 12]]).flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [a],"col2":[b]})
df.loc[1] = (b,a)

df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

print(df.compute())

name_function = lambda x: f"data-{x}.parquet"
df[['col1','col2']].to_parquet('train/',name_function=name_function,engine='pyarrow',schema={"col1": pa.list_(pa.int32()),"col2": pa.list_(pa.int32())})


df2 = dd.read_parquet(['train/data-0.parquet','train/data-1.parquet'])  
print(df2.compute())

def reshape(x):
    if(x == 'foo'):
        return x
    return x.reshape(2,2) 

df2 = df2.applymap(lambda x:reshape(x)) 
print(df2.compute())
```

```
              col1             col2
0     [5, 6, 7, 8]  [9, 10, 11, 12]
1  [9, 10, 11, 12]     [5, 6, 7, 8]
              col1             col2
0     [5, 6, 7, 8]  [9, 10, 11, 12]
1  [9, 10, 11, 12]     [5, 6, 7, 8]
                  col1                 col2
0     [[5, 6], [7, 8]]  [[9, 10], [11, 12]]
1  [[9, 10], [11, 12]]     [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

I hope there is another more simple solution.